# Word stores into wrong address in dynamically allocated array in MIPS/MARS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I dynamically allocate 48 bits using syscall 9 and then iterate through it setting t0-t3 and s0-s1 to different addresses (like arrays of 2 elements).

And it looks like this in register window:

$t0 0x10040000

$t1 0x10040008

$t2 0x10040010

$t3 0x10040018

$s0 0x10040020

$s1 0x10040028

Then I proceed to get user input to put them into the arrays. 
When I store first input with `sw $v0, ($t0)` it goes into Value(+4) in debugger window not into Value(+0).

Later on, when I process arrays it messes with addresses and rewrites them instead of writing to the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

It stored numbers in right addresses the problem was in wrong numbers displaying in MARS (I debugged it just printing out numbers)